# In Gatling, how can I create a key value pair from returned body and save it in the session?

Tags: scala, gatling

So I execute a POST call and get a few objects in return. 
I would like to extract and create a key value pair and save it in the session for later use.

My current code looks as follows:

```
.exec(http(“Rest call“)
  .post("/api")
  .body(ElFileBody("json/api.json")).asJson
  .check(jsonPath("$.result.objects[*].files[?(@.type == ‘FILE1’)].id").findAll.saveAs(“id”))
  .check(jsonPath("$.result.objects[*].files[?(@.type == ‘FILE1’)].name”).findAll.saveAs(“name”))
```

Here I end up with two lists(Vectors) in my session, "id" and "name".
What I would like to do is create one list of key/value pairs of id/name instead. Obviously the pairs should correlate to the same jsonpath hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is using scala's collection zipping in a session function

```
.exec(http(“Rest call“)
  .post("/api")
  .body(ElFileBody("json/api.json")).asJson
  .check(jsonPath("$.result.objects[*].files[?(@.type == ‘FILE1’)].id").findAll.saveAs(“id”))
  .check(jsonPath("$.result.objects[*].files[?(@.type == ‘FILE1’)].name”).findAll.saveAs(“name”)
)
.exec(session => {
  var ids = session("id").as[Seq[String]]
  var names = session("name").as[Seq[String]]
  session.set("pairs", ids zip names)
})
```

this will set a session variable called "pairs", with the contents being a List of Tuple2

check out https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-merge-sequential-collection-pairs-zip-unzip-scala-cookbook

Comment: Hello! :) Just wondering how safe is the order of the two Seq since those come out of a parser. If I do the same with the css() extractor will the order be guaranteed? Thanks for any response!